# Retagging Questions Based on Answers

Tags: discussion, retagging

I can see many instances where this is the case, but here's the most common scenario I encounter:

A user asks a question about `query_posts()` or `get_posts()` but the correct answer should use `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts`.

Should the question get retagged with the proper technique? If so, I imagine it would be in addition to the original tag.

Comment: very good point indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a question on Meta.SO a long time ago: [Should we retag questions with topics proposed in the answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59333/should-we-retag-questions-with-topics-proposed-in-the-answers) where the accepted answer says **No**.

But … if someone is asking for an attempted *solution* without understanding the actual *problem* the answer may be very different from the original wording of the question (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). I think it is useful to find such answers via tags.

When I'm searching for examples of `'pre_get_posts'` filters (I actually *did* that) then those answers should not be hidden due to a over-restrictive tag policy. That's why I tag *content*, not just *questions*. Make it easy to find good content.

Comment: I'll post this as a separate Meta question, but: should we always look to Meta.SO as the definitive answer for our Meta questions? While site mechanics are consistent across the SE network, each site *is* different, meets different needs, and is comprised of different users.

Comment: @ChipBennett We have to find our own informal rules. That's why we have a separate meta. :) I see meta.so as a source for more perspectives and background information.

Answer (score 3):

Using `query_posts()` as the example: if the correct/accepted answer uses a different function - more accurately, uses a more correct *implementation technique*, then I say **yes**: re-tag the question. But *more importantly*, you should also **edit the question** to reflect a more-general question.

To generalize the example, I see this as a case where a user asks, "*how do I use this not-best-case (or worse, wrong) implementation method to do X?*", and the community responds with an explanation regarding *why* the OP's implementation method is wrong, along with a solution using the correct/best-practice method. In such cases, it is useful to generalize the question, and re-tag.

I don't know how far that answer extends to *other* use cases/scenarios, though.

Comment: This is interesting. To what extent does one rewrite the question? If they're using the wrong technique, it seems like the rewritten question would be almost completely replaced. Is there an example with a changelog you could share to illustrate?

Comment: No I don't. I'm proposing what *should* be done, not what necessarily *has* been done. Part of the problem with the example use case is `query_posts()` itself, which, based on core-developer comments, may one day soon die in a fire. A better example of a similar question might be one that asks, "*how do I **modify core** to...?*". We might be3 able to find examples of such questions that would fit this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

No, not usually. The tags refer to the question, not the answers. People searching WPSE will be looking for similar questions (or browsing by tag) - either way, if their question is 'should I use `query_posts()` they won't be searching for `pre_get_posts`.

In fact, its exactly when the answers correct a bad practise, that these tags become very useful, pointing others to the 'correct' practise.

Comment: I think that's a good reason to not _replace_ the old "incorrect" tag with a new "correct" tag, but what about in addition to it?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. Replace, no. But adding in addition to... I would say err on saying yes - but these things need to be taken on a case by case basis.