# Should we retag basted on answer?

Tags: discussion, retagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retagging Questions Based on Answers](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/retagging-questions-based-on-answers)

If a question has an accepted answer that introduces a new topic to the question, should the question be retagged to accommodate this new topic?

For example, if someone has a problem with their site, and the solution is something to do with their .htaccess file, should the [.htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) tag be added to the question?